# Easiest way to convert a bash string into an array in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to convert a string variable into an array to iterate over the elements in Bash

This is my variable:

```
items="component01 component02 component03"
echo $items
>> component01 component02 component03
```

I tried with `items=($items)` but when I check with `echo ${#items[@]}` I get just one single element so I can't iterate over the elements with a for loop.

Also, I cannot make use of `read -a` as I can't use it in macOS.

Comment: What's your version of bash? `items=($items) ; echo "${#items[@]}"` gives me 3 on 4.1.2.

Comment: If there were a good way to do this, `bash` wouldn't need arrays. `items=($items)` works fine, as long as none of the "items" is supposed to contain whitespace (or elements that could be subject to pathname expansion). `read -a arr <<< "$items"` is a possibility, but suffers from the same whitespace issue that led to the introduction of arrays in the first place.

Comment: `read -a` is supported in the (ancient) default version of Bash on macOS.  It's a good option for solving your problem.  You may be thinking of `readarray`.  It was introduced in a later version of Bash, but it's not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Have you changed `IFS`? If not, `read -a items <<<"$items"` should work (yes, even in bash v3.2.57 that ships in macOS). If you have changed `IFS`... that'll cause a variety of problems, and you should change it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your items split with whitespace, and none of your items of array does not have whitespace in itself, you can use this way to change it to array

```
arr=(`echo $items`)
```

Comment: This one has worked in my case. Thanks.

Comment: This is pointlessly complex -- the `echo` and the backticks basically cancel each other out (other than adding more opportunities for weird parsing behavior), so this is mostly equivalent to `arr=($items)`. See [Shellcheck warning SC2116: "Useless echo? Instead of `cmd $(echo foo)`, just use `cmd foo`"](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2116) (and obviously, if you run the script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), it will point this out).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get it into an array per se but you can iterate through it as is provided $IFS=

```
#!/bin/bash

string="component01 component02 component03"
for s in $string
do
  echo $s
done
```

yields:

```
$ ./iterate.sh
component01
component02
component03
```

This works out of the box provided your IFS is set to the default space characters (tab, space, newline I think).

Just in case:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(3)-release (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming space is the separator

```
IFS=" " a=( $items )
```